# Integral of derivative of polynomial over polynomial on a circle

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, polynomials

Let $p$ be a polynomial of degree $n$ and $R>0$ such that $|z_0|<R$ for all zeros $z_0$ of $p$. Show that
$$\int_{|z|=R}  {p'(z)\over p(z)} \, dz = 2in\pi$$

I know I have to use Cauchy's Integral Formula but I am not quite sure how. I have thought about breaking up the polynomial into linear factors but I am not clear on what that would bring me considering that the derivative will break up into completely different linear factors. I have tried using the standard definition of an integral over a curve but have gotten nowhere with that.

Comment: If you had the Argument Principle available you would be done, because this is just the special case of a polynomial.  Otherwise you're left proving the Argument Principle in the case of a polynomial.  At a zero, say $z_0$ write $p(z)=(z-z_0)^kf(z)$ where $k$ is the multiplicity of the zero at $z_0$ and $f(z_0)\neq 0$.  Compute the derivative, look at $p'(z)/p(z)$, and calculate the residue at $z_0$.  Spoiler alert - it should be $k$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were on the right track, splitting into linear factors. The joke is: $$\frac{p'(z)}{p(z)}=\sum_k\frac{1}{z-z_k},$$ where $z_k$ are all zeroes of $p$. That's true even if some of the $z_k$ are equal (it may be even true if $p$ is not a polynomial and there are infinite zeroes, but that's tricky).
Can you go on from that?

Comment: The OP would like to see that  since $p$ is a polynomial $$p(z) = C \prod_{k=1}^n (z-z_k), \ \log p(z) =\log (C)+\sum_{k=1}^n \log(z-z_k), \ \frac{p'(z)}{p(z)} = \frac{d \log p(z)}{dz}=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{z-z_k}$$

Comment: Yes, of course, that's why I called it a joke: it's really easy if you know what you're looking for. And that's why I asked "can you go on...?". If not, I'd have posted exactly that

Comment: Where is this $\log p(z)$ defined, and how you know the $\log$ of the product is the sum of the $\log$s?

Comment: Alright, thanks guys. With this I can then turn the integral over the sum into a sum over integrals and then use Cauchy's Integral Formula for the constant function 1 to get the result. Thanks again!